# Ctrl+A suddenly becomes Home. What did I do?

Tags: shortcut-keys, keyboard

Earlier today, I was tweaking my fresh Ubuntu 12.04 installation. I added and removed (and purged) several PPAs and also installed GNOME Shell. It wasn't working the way I had intended it, so I removed it from the system.

Strangely enough -- and I don't know if GNOME Shell might be responsible -- anytime I try to select all text (ie `Ctrl+A`), the cursor just goes back to the beginning of the line (like the `Home` key).

Does anybody know what I did so I can avoid doing the same mistake, and have a solution to that?

Sorry for my bad English

**EDIT:**
Okay, I did `egrep -irl "&gt;a" ~/.gconf/` but there was no output.
Also, `Ctrl+D` becomes `Del` and `Ctrl+F` moves the cursor forward one character. This is getting weirder and weirder.

Comment: @desgua Okay, did that. Nothing, unfortunately.

Comment: what program are you trying to do this in?  Is it gnome-terminal, or a GUI application?   The shortcuts you are describing sound like command-line terminal commands.

Comment: @ImaginaryRobots Everywhere

Comment: @desgua: Yes, there was. I missed that, sorry. D:

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you don't have Gnome Tweak Tool, [install](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/gnome-tweak-tool) and then run it.  You should see at "Theme" the option "Keybinding theme" that you should set to "Default" instead of "Emacs":

[image]

Comment: Thank you. This did the trick. I didn't realized I had changed it. I feel stupid now.

Comment: Don't feel bad, we forget things when trying to tweak or learn something new ;-)

Answer (score 0):

```
gsettings reset org.gnome.desktop.interface gtk-key-theme
```

Comment: Could you add some additional details and context to this and explain how and, perhaps, what this command is doing?